# Convert numeric to date in yyyy-mm format in R

Tags: r, date, format, numeric

I have a column of numerics like `200910` and `201211` that I want to convert into date object of the format yyyy-mm. `as.Date(as.character(200910),'%Y%m')` does not work.

Comment: Look at `as.yearmon`.

Comment: A month and a year does not make a date. You also need a day.

Answer (score 0):

Add a day to each date:

```
foo <- c("200910", "201211")
foo <- paste0(foo, "01")
foo <- as.Date(foo, "%Y%m%d")
foo
[1] "2009-10-01" "2012-11-01"
```

Answer (score 0):

At max, you could do this using `zoo` package's function `as.yearmon()`

```
> library(zoo)
> as.yearmon(c("200910","201211"),format="%Y%m")
[1] "Oct 2009" "Nov 2012"
```